# Conflicting Scripts (javascript and jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scripting, conflict

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prototype.lite.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.csvToTable.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $('#CSVTable_Pach').CSVToTable... 
    });
```

The script on top is part of a lightbox feature, however it is not allowing a table to display.

How can i resolve the conflict between these scripts?

[link to the site](http://www.rankingclub.com/games.htm)

Comment: Have you tried [$.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be having a conflict because both libraries use the $ shortcut. Look into the noconflict feature of jQuery or the equivalent of prototype.

You can read more here: **[jQuery ... Avoiding Conflicts with Other Libraries](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)**